# Returns posts with most recent comments by user as well as posts with no comments

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

Using Rails and Postgres I'm working on a complex SQL query to return all posts with the following conditions:

1. The last comment published for each post was not authored by a specific user; OR
2. The post has no comments

I've built the query to return posts where the last comment published was not authored by that specific user, but I can't work out how to modify this to also return the posts which don't have a comment.

```
 Post 
  .joins(:comments)
  .joins(
    "INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (commentable_type, commentable_id) commentable_type, commentable_id, id
      FROM comments
      WHERE comments.author_id != #{user.id}
      ORDER BY commentable_type, commentable_id, created_at DESC, id
    ) most_recent_comments ON (
      most_recent_comments.id = comments.id
    )"
  )
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Think I've figured it out actually. I need to use `includes` to do a left outer join on comments and then do the same in the second `joins` method:

```
 Post 
  .includes(:comments)
  .joins(
    "LEFT outer JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT ON (commentable_type, commentable_id) commentable_type, commentable_id, id
      FROM comments
      WHERE comments.author_id != #{user.id}
      ORDER BY commentable_type, commentable_id, created_at DESC, id
    ) most_recent_comments ON (
      most_recent_comments.id = comments.id
    )"
  )
```